# TFS Queue Background Jobs permission

Tags: tfs

We would like to have a process which runs a [script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx) that forces an Active Sync of TFS (the Active Directory TFS sync job ordinarily only runs once an hour). Based on my understanding of [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/37d4e4fc-d05e-4d11-8fa8-4f7c11de38e1/active-directory-usergroup-sync-?forum=winserverDS) post (which discusses using a command line program to accomplish the same end result), the calling account would need to have the **Queue Background Jobs** TFS permission granted.

Without this permission attempting to execute the PowerShell script, I receive the following error:

> Exception calling "QueueJobNow" with "2" argument(s): "Access Denied: Smith, Jane needs the following permission(s) on the 
>   resource AllJobs to perform this action: Queue background jobs"

It is not clear how one would grant the **Queue Background Jobs** permission. It does not appear to be in the TFS Console or GUI anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This permission is granted via the `tfsecurity` command. You will need to grant the **Job** namespace  **Queue** and **Read** permissions as depicted below in order for the PowerShell script referenced in the question to work:

To see current security assignments:

`tfssecurity /acl job /server:https://myserver/tfs`

To grant a user read job information:

`tfssecurity /a+ Job AllJobs Read n:mydomain\myuser ALLOW /server:https://myserver/tfs`

To remove a user’s read job information:
`tfssecurity /a- Job AllJobs Read n:mydomain\myuser ALLOW /server:https://myserver/tfs`

To grant a user queue job access:

`tfssecurity /a+ Job AllJobs Queue n:mydomain\myuser ALLOW /server:https://myserver/tfs`

To remove a user’s queue job access:

`tfssecurity /a- Job AllJobs Queuen:mydomain\myuser ALLOW /server:https://myserver/tfs`

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I will; however since I answered my own question, I have to wait 2 days from the original posting to do that.